# Могу ли я разбить строку из потока строк в поток символов?

Tags: java, java-stream

У меня есть поток строк `Stream.of("foo", "egg")`, я хочу каждую строку разбить на поток символов и работать дальше уже с каждым символом по отдельности.

Например, вывести символ и после него восклицательный знак

```
f!o!o!e!g!g!
```

Я думал, что это можно сделать как-то так.

```
Stream.of("foo", "egg").flatMap(s -> s.chars()).forEach(c-> System.out.print(c+"!"));
```

Но компилятор ругается на такое решение

Comment: Используйте flatMapToInt

Comment: Благодарю, помогло `Stream.of("foo", "egg").flatMapToInt(CharSequence::chars).forEach(c-> System.out.print((char) c+"!"));`